# SNS has gone can't be re enabled again

Tags: email, stock-android, facebook, android-sdk, yahoo-mail

Following this thread

http://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-s4/296366-facebook-log-sync-applications.html

I have disabled the SNS service

now Yahoo mail app does not notify for Facebook emails, it does notify about everything else. In status bar i got the emails but not from facebook and if i manually refresh email list i get the facebook email but no notification about it.

I tried to uninstall facebook and yahoo mail then re install them but SNS still missing from services > All

Now everytime i login to facebook i get this annoying (other type of message) Samsung galaxy would like to access your account if i add the sync it keeps asking me again each time i login. It was 
"Log in to sync Facebook with your other applications" message before disabling the SNS

What can i do please help? Been hours i am trying with no avail.

Comment: If you can't re-enable SNS,then it sounds like you ended up disabling something that the SNS was dependent on. Recheck all other disabled apps.

Comment: That's the biggest problem. There is no longer SNS app under all applications. And no any other app that has been disabled.

Comment: Go into *settings>apps>all apps>*, then scroll to the bottom (first will be enabled apps a-z, then second will be disabled apps a-z)...if not following it then it should be in its own tab (disabled apps) after all apps.

Comment: I have checked every single App there is just no more "SNS" no disabled apps too. Have a look here http://i.imgur.com/tSUKuw8.png and http://i.imgur.com/jSik82h.png I think there is no solution but to do a factory reset damn :(

Comment: Did you try re-installing SNS.apk? Here is a link to SNS.apk [https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=13858035414129967191](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=13858035414129967191). Its for S2 epic 4gtouch, but should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to install the apk but unfortunately APP installed  error http://i.imgur.com/CKBU3eI.png :(

Comment: Looks like a factory-reset. Backup your photos and other info first.

Comment: BUT did you uninstall facebook first before installing SNS?

Comment: Yes Facebook is already removed and still same error App not installed. Going to last unwanted .solution factory reset :(

Comment: Sorry that link didn't help. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks HasH . The SNS has been restored after factory reset however the main problem still exists. Facebook emails go silent to Yahoo mail with no notifications (I tested sending email my self from my gmail to yahoo i get the notification email in status bar fine). I can't seem to find the cause of this problem.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the SNS Managers on the Play Store? There's a few that look promising for notification control. Might help on re-establishing connection between the two.

Comment: After long day of trying and searching i think i finally found the solution to this problem. I have tried to use Gmail and that does not get notifications about Social emails too so i thought it is a generic problem. Turns out that gmail splits the emails into categories and the Social category has notifications off by default. So what i did i have turn the inbox type to Default and went to settings > manage labels then enabled notifications and notifications about every message. So i think this is a problem from Yahoo SmartView feature.

Comment: If it works, take your comments and form an answer - comprehensive as possible. Then accept your answer. You did all the work. And kudos for the perseverance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after i tried everything to recover the SNS process nothing has worked but a factory reset, however Yahoo mail still gets Facebook emails without notifications so i am guessing this is a problem at their end. I would not recommend to stop the SNS process to get rid of the message **"login to sync facebook with your other applications"** as you can see a small issue turned into a big one. I am using Gmail now to get Facebook emails and everything works just fine. Big thanks goes to HasH_BrowN for trying to help me out solving this issue.